# Assigning task to mutiple users in scrpted assignment of kaleo worlflow of liferay

Tags: workflow, liferay, liferay-6

I have created a workflow using kaleo workflow.In this i am trying to assign a task to multiple users,I used groovy script in scripted assignment tag for this.But its not working .when am putting two userid's in user object,first one gets replaced and second user got the approvel task.
also i used users arraylist for this,like roles in kaleo single approver scripted assignment definition.but no use.

How can i manage this.

This is my code.

```
            roles=null;
            Connection con = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String secondid;
            try
            {                   

            Class.forName(dbDriver);
            con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,dbUser,dbPwd);

                stmt = con.createStatement();                   
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("select ap1,ap2 from test where id = '"+userId+"'");
                users=new ArrayList<User>();                    
                while (rs.next()) 
                    {                       
                    println "approverid one"+rs.getInt(1);
                    println "approverid two"+rs.getInt(2);
                       user=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(Long.parseLong(rs.getString(1)));
user=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(Long.parseLong(rs.getString(2)));

                    users.add(user);
                    println "array list:"+users;
                    }
                rs.close(); 
                con.close();                
             }                              
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           

            ]]>
    </script>
            <script-language>groovy</script-language>
        </scripted-assignment>
```

when am adding two user id in user tag.also it indicate  error in definition while uploading.

Comment: I am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In short, use roles. In the control panel, you can specify roles and add users to them. Or, if you'd rather do it programmatically, (Though I would still create the role beforehand) something like this:
(And I'm assuming you can get or have an array of userIds

```
//Already created array of userIds like
// [10180,10191], etc.
roles=new ArrayList<Role>();
try {
    Role r = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, roleName);
    if (r.getType()==RoleConstants.TYPE_REGULAR) {
        UserLocalServiceUtil.addRoleUsers(r.getRoleId(), userIds);
    } else {
        UserGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.addUserGroupRoles(userIds, groupId, r.getRoleId());
    }
    roles.add(r);
} catch (SystemException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (PortalException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Just toss that or some approximation of that or a call to that in your scripted-assignment definition. If you need to, use `UserLocalServiceUtil.unsetRoleUsers` or something similar to clear out the old users from the role first.